# Creating an array of strings through user input in c?

Tags: c, arrays, character, scanf

I'm new to C so some clarification would be very helpful! I'm trying to use a scanner to ask my program for a series of words which I will store..what I have so far is,

```
     char[]listOfWords[9999]; //creates a large array of characters
     scanf("%s", listOfWords); //stores inputs into listOfWords
```

with this, I can access the first word easily, but it comes to a matter of accessing the second, and third words..any suggestion? For example, how my input was

```
 Hello how are you guys
```

I can access "Hello" no problem,  but how would I call "how" and "are"

Comment: `char[]listOfWords[9999];` won't compile. As for the problem, `%s` reads until it finds a whitespace character. You can call the `scanf` again and again to read each word. Or simply use `scanf("%[^\n]", listOfWords);` to read in the whole line. Note that the previous approach will fail if the first character to be read by it is a `\n` and also, it will leave a newline character in the `stdin`. Another approach would be to use `fgets(listOfWords, sizeof(listOfWords), stdin);`. Note that `fgets` consumes the newline character and stores it in `listOfWords`.

Comment: `char[]listOfWords[9999];` ......definitely not C...

Comment: yeah, I used [100] I was just rushing through my methodology my apologies. That is an interesting technique, thank you! My problem is, if I were to use it that way, how would I know blindly the length of every word? Since I believe this will just create a long array of characters like

Comment: [h,e,l,l,o, ,,h,o,w,...]

Comment: @user201535 If you were to read the whole line into `listOfWords`, you need to use `strtok` with space as the delimiter to get each word. Then, use `strlen` to find the length of each word.

Answer (score 1):

This - `char[]listOfWords[9999];` is not a valid syntax to declare array.

You simply need to declare an array -

```
char s[100];  
fgets(s,100,stdin);  // take input and store it in s
```

And using [`strtok`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) or [`sscanf`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm) you can extract separate words in different arrays .

Or you can use a 2-d array -

```
char s[100][100];
```

So if string stored in it is - `Hello how are you guys`

then by `s[0]` you will get `Hello` , `s[1]` will give `how` and similarly , other words in string.

Comment: shouldn't be **fgets(s,99,stdin);** ?

Comment: @Michi Why ? `fgets` will add `null character` at the end .

Comment: I was asking because if you get 100 letters + '\0' it will be 101. or will be only 99 here **fgets(s,100,stdin);** ?

Comment: @Michi No I don't that will happen . It will stop as  `100-1`(in general `n-1`) i.e (`99`) characters are read . `n` being size given to it .

Comment: didn't know that, i always used scanf. So if you add 15 to fgets you get 14 letters + '\0' .

Comment: @Michi Yes . You can read it here - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Answer (score 1):

Scanf() only accepts input for a single word.(not after space.)

To enter multiple words, you can use **gets(string)** or **scanf("%[^\n]", string).**

Comment: `gets` is dangerous and has been deprecated as of the latest C standard. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: "_Scanf() only accepts input for a single word_" -- That's misleading. The format specifier, specifically `%s` , is responsible for that.

Comment: Though fgets is a better option, Still gets is more convenient some times. (At least I feel so. it keeps away from file operations.)  Even if you dont want to use it, use scanf option .

Comment: @CoolGuy This sentence was accordilg to the example in question not in general.

Answer (score 1):

- Here is a code what you are looking fore,

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main()
  {
     char str[5][10];

     printf("enter the strings...\n");
     for(int i =0; i < 5; i++)
     scanf("%s", str[i]);

     printf("All strings are...\n");
     for(int j =0; j < 5; j++)
     printf("%s\n", str[j]);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem to read multiple words? Or just reading a full line? Also the declaration `char[]listOfWords[9999]` is wrong. If you all you want to do is read a line, you can try the following:

```
char buffer[1024];
fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);
```